# jQuery slider - 2nd click changes display to none before width animation

Tags: jquery, css

I have this code

```
$(".guitar").toggle(function() {
    $(".guitar_content").click().animate({width: "500"}, 1000).css({display: "block"});
    $(".guitar_text").delay(1200).animate({ opacity: "1"}, 600);
}, function() {
    $(".guitar_content").click().animate({ width: "0" }, 1000);
    $(".guitar_content").delay(1000).css({ display: "none"});
});
​
```

My problem is when i click the second time it changes the display to none before it runs the width animation even with the delay i have added.

How can i get it to do the width animation before changing the css.

this is my project http://jsfiddle.net/TvLMQ/

Comment: @Michael, you don't need to write `css` in the title, the `css` tag is enough... `:)`

Answer (score 2):

Use a callback instead of the `.delay`:

```
$(".guitar_content").click().animate({width: "0"},1000, function(){
    $(this).css({display: "none"});
});
```